# GCP - IAM policy update failed - Allow unauthenticated invocations

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, google-cloud-run, squarespace, google-iam

I'm the owner of my organisation, but when I try to make my cloud run services public (security -> Allow unauthenticated invocations), I get this error:

IAM policy update failed
A domain restriction organisation policy is in place. Only principals in allowed domains can be added as principals in the policy. Correct the principal emails and try again.

I don't understand the error, because I am connected as the owner. I created this organisation a few days ago, I immediately had this problem.

I've tried lots of commands and checking IAM rights, but nothing works.

I'm totally stuck,I need your help, please.

I tried update I AM roles via commands, check DNS records (squarespace) & domain. Everything looks good for me. But unfortunately the error persists.

Comment: Can you check the Domain Restriction Sharing policy for your org AND for your project? That's the policy that block the public sharing of Cloud Run

Comment: Thanks you very much, you are my hero ! I added the rule Allow All in my "Domain restricted sharing" org policy, and it solved my problem ! I wish you all the best !

Comment: Stay tuned at Cloud Next next month, something new will be announced to mitigate the issue with the DRS org policy.

Answer (score 0):

Steps that solved my problem :

Go to : I AM & Admin > Organization policies > "Domain restricted sharing"

Applies to : Customize (unchanged)
Policy enforcement : replace (unchanged)
Rules : add a rule > Policy values : Allow All